# How can I add a shadow to a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, quartz-graphics

I'd like to add a little drop shadow to a grouped UITableView that I have. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to the table as a whole, to each section, to a cell, or something else? There are no built-in methods to do this; you'll have to do some custom drawing or use pre-rendered background images.

Comment: I want a shadow behind the tableview as a whole

Comment: if you have `image` then please edit this question..

Comment: Does that imply that your table view is not full-screen (or takes up the full containing view)? There are few UI circumstances in which you'd want to do that; what are you trying to do? If you don't want blur in your shadow, you can simply put another view with a fill set to a shadow color behind your table view, offset by a bit in the direction you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the bacground image for a cell you can give that effect for when you select the cell or not. The image would have to carry that effect on it.

Comment: Yes I used custom cells that have a shadow baked into the image. http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html